# Fazer busca usando 2 tipos de info num mesmo campo texto!

Tags: asp.net, razor

Estou tentando num filtro com Razor, buscar no mesmo campo texto, 2 informações, você pode digitar CNPJ ou carteira, quando carrego a página das solicitações, já carrega com os dados de CNPJ e Carteira na tela, mas tenho um botao procurar que quando se digita um dos dois, por exemplo CNPJ, o campo Carteira vem vazio, eu consegui fazer isso na Controller, mas gostaria de fazer direto no HTML Razor, vejamos a seguir as regras:

PartialFiltro.cshtml

```html
@model DPE.Programa.Dados.Models.tb_solicitacao
<div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
            <span>Cnpj/Carteira:<br>
            </span>
            @if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.cnpj))
            {
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.carteira"  id="carteira" name="carteira" aria-expanded="true" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.cnpj"  id="cnpj" name="cnpj" aria-expanded="true" />
            }
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control" value=" @if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.cnpj)) { @Model.carteira  } else { @Model.cnpj } "  id="carteira" name="carteira" aria-expanded="true" />*@
</div>
<button class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-labeled fa fa-search" type="button" id="btn-pesquisar">Pesquisar</button>
```

Podemos ver que no que fiz sempre vai carregar dados do Carteira que é um número assim 128272, ai trás no resultado.

Agora a controler onde tem comentado que consegui fazer a busca por CNPJ quando digitar no campo, pegava pelo tamanho dele.

```js
public ActionResult FiltroPesquisa(tb_solicitacao filtros, int? pagina)
        {
            try
            {
                    return PartialView("PartialResultadoPesquisa", ListarDados(filtros, pagina));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExibirMensagem("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar o filtro.<br/>Erro: " + ex.Message, ETipoMensagem.Erro, 99);
                return PartialView("_ControleMensagem");
            }
        }

        public List<tb_solicitacao> ListarDados(tb_solicitacao filtros, int? pagina)
        {
            _paginacao.PageNumber = pagina ?? 1;
            _paginacao.RowspPage = 10;

            using (DB_ConsultaDomicilioContext context = new DB_ConsultaDomicilioContext())
            {
                
                var model = context.tb_solicitacao.Include("tb_credenciamento_solicitacao").Include("tb_faturamento_solicitacao").Include("tb_faturamento_flex_solicitacao").AsQueryable(); 

                //var auxCarteira = String.Empty;

                //FILTROS
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtros.cnpj))
                    model = model.Where(f => f.cnpj.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(filtros.cnpj.ToUpper().Trim()));

                //if (filtros.cnpj.Length < 9)
                //{
                //    auxCarteira = filtros.cnpj;
                //    filtros.carteira = auxCarteira;
                //    filtros.cnpj = "";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtros.carteira))
                    model = model.Where(f => f.carteira.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(filtros.carteira.ToUpper().Trim()));
                //}
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtros.email_solicitante))
                    model = model.Where(f => f.email_solicitante.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(filtros.email_solicitante.ToUpper().Trim()));
                if (filtros.data_email != DateTime.MinValue && filtros.data_email != null)
                    model = model.Where(f => f.data_email.ToShortDateString() == filtros.data_email.ToShortDateString());
                if (filtros.data_cadastro != DateTime.MinValue && filtros.data_email != null)
                    model = model.Where(f => f.data_cadastro.ToShortDateString() == filtros.data_cadastro.ToShortDateString());
                //Filtro Status
                if (filtros.id_status != 0)
                    model = model.Where(f => f.id_status == filtros.id_status);

                model = model.OrderByDescending(f => f.data_cadastro).AsQueryable();

                _paginacao.TotalRegistros = model.Count();
                _listDados = model.Skip(_paginacao.PageNumber * _paginacao.RowspPage - _paginacao.RowspPage).Take(_paginacao.RowspPage).ToList();

                ViewBag.PaginacaoManual = _paginacao;
                return _listDados;
            }
        }
```

E por fim a tela que modifiquei para mostrar os dados quando for CNPJ ou Carteira ou mostra carregando tudo.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    @{
        
        if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-vcenter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                    <th class="text-center">CNPJ</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Carteira</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Data Email</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Data Entrada</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Resposta</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    var Status = Utilitario.EnumDescription((Itau.DPE.ConsultaDomicilio.Dados.Enumeradores.EStatusSolicitacao)item.id_status);
                    var auxCnpj = item.cnpj;
                    var auxCarteira = item.carteira;
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.id_solicitacao</td>
                        @if (auxCnpj != "")
                        {
                            <td class="text-center">@item.cnpj</td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                        }
                        else if (auxCarteira != null)
                        {
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.carteira</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td class="text-center">@item.cnpj</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.carteira</td>   
                        }
                        <td class="text-center icon-email-solicitacao" data-details="@Html.Raw(item.mensagem_email.Replace("nbsp", "<br />"))" title="Detalhe" style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer">
                            @item.email_solicitante</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.data_email</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.data_cadastro</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Status</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @if (Status == "Respondida")
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="icon-detalhe-solicitacao" id="@item.id_solicitacao">
                                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                </a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
                Html.RenderPartial("_Paginacao");
        }
        else
        {
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="text-center">Não houve resultados para a pesquisa. </th>
            </tr>

        </table>        
        }     
    }
</div>
```

Foco principal é na primeira tela, estou tentando bolar um jeito de conseguir pesquisar por qualquer um dos dois, mas apenas por carteira consegui, alguém já fez esse tipo de busca ou tem alguma ideia do que eu poderia mudar para dar certo no ASP.NET, valeu galera.

Comment: Tive dificuldade pra entender qual o comportamento esperado da aplicação. Poderia explicar melhor o que não está funcionando corretamente ou o que exatamente você quer melhorar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Pessoal,

Encontrei uma resposta a minha dúvida em pesquisar tanto por CNPJ ou Carteira ao digitar no campo texto, o objetivo é carregar na tela web informações com estas pesquisas diferentes, fiz um filtro abaixo no meu método, espero que ajude a quem precisar e quero agradecer a todos que viram e que me apoiaram, segue abaixo:

```
 public List<tb_solicitacao> ListarDados(tb_solicitacao filtros, int? pagina)
 {
     using (DB_ConsultaDomicilioContext context = new DB_ConsultaDomicilioContext())
     {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtros.cnpj))
            {
                var auxCNPJCarteira = filtros.cnpj.Trim();
                model = model.Where(f => f.cnpj.Contains(auxCNPJCarteira) || f.carteira.Contains(auxCNPJCarteira));
            }
     }
 }
```

Atenciosamente,
Leandro de Azevedo.